# Проблемы с BackgroundWorker!

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, backgroundworker

Я новичок в C#.
 При работе с BackgroundWorker возник казус. При получении данных с базы данных все происходит гладко. Однако при присваивании e.Result = dataTable пишет что **e.Result = '"e.Result" выдал исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException"**

```
private void BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string Refresh = "dbo.GetRenderedService '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date.ToString() + "','" + dateTimePicker4.Value.Date.ToString() + "'";
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable = DbConnection.DBConnect(Refresh);

                int i = 1;

                //foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
                //{
                //    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
                //    //Thread.Sleep(1);
                //    i++;
                //}
                e.Result = (Object)dataTable;

        }
```

Дебагом пробежался по коду и выявил, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста с данной проблемой! Как это решить?

Comment: Для полной картины не хватает инициализации самого BackgroundWorker1 и указанных разработчиков событий. Может там собака порылась. Хотя честно говоря ситуация странная.

Comment: И код обработчика dowork точно приведен весь?

Comment: @skingreek Приведен весь